# Array multisort in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
Array (
 [0] => Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [value-a] => 230.00 [value-b] => 1610.00 [value-c] => 3.00)
 [1] => Array ( [value-a] => 170.00 [value-b] => 1190.00 [value-c] => 4.00)
 [2] => Array ( [value-a] => 170.00 [value-b] => 1190.00 [value-c] => 2.00)
 )
)
```

How can I sort ascending by value-b and then by value-c?

Comment: it is impossible to have two indexes "1"

Comment: sorry my misake it is "2" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove first array wrapper:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [value-a] => 230.00 [value-b] => 1610.00 [value-c] => 3.00)
        [1] => Array ( [value-a] => 170.00 [value-b] => 1190.00 [value-c] => 4.00)
        [2] => Array ( [value-a] => 170.00 [value-b] => 1190.00 [value-c] => 2.00)
    )
)
```

to

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [value-a] => 230.00 [value-b] => 1610.00 [value-c] => 3.00)
    [1] => Array ( [value-a] => 170.00 [value-b] => 1190.00 [value-c] => 4.00)
    [2] => Array ( [value-a] => 170.00 [value-b] => 1190.00 [value-c] => 2.00)
)
```

and here you can use usort() function : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php